# PDF and CDF of Ratio distribution in specific cases

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Consider two  random variables $X$ and $Y$. I would like to derive the PDF and CDF of $$Z=\frac{X}{\max(X,Y)}.$$ The direct method would be to derive distributions for the numerator and denominator and then the ratio. But I am trying to do this slightly differently.

The way I see it there are two cases: $Z_1=X/X$ and $Z_2 = X/Y$. For $Z_1$ the CDF is
$$
F_{Z_1}(z) = P(X/X \le z) =  
\begin{cases}
    0 ,& \text{if } z < 1\\
    1,              & z \ge 1.
\end{cases} 
$$
For $Z_2 = X/Y$ the CDF is less straightforward but assume the PDF $f_{Z_2}(z)$ is known. Then
$$
F_{Z_2}(z)  =
    \int_{-\infty}^{z}f_{Z_2}(x)dx.
$$
How can I stitch these pieces together into a CDF and PDF for the original $Z$?

My guess:
$$
F_Z(z) =  
\begin{cases}
    F_{Z_2}(z) ,& \text{if } z < 1\\
    1,              & z \ge 1
\end{cases} 
$$
There is likely a discontinuity at $z=1$ but we differentiate to obtain
$$
f_Z(z) =  
\begin{cases}
    f_{Z_2}(z) ,& \text{if } z < 1\\
    \delta(z-1),              & z \ge 1
\end{cases} 
$$

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that you know how to calculate $P(X\leq zY)$ for any $z$...

Following your logic, 
$$
Z=\begin{cases}
1, & X>Y\\
\frac{X}{Y}, & X\leq Y.
\end{cases}
$$
Then using conditional probability, for any $z\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
P(Z\leq z)=P(Z\leq z|X>Y)P(X>Y)+P(Z\leq z|X\leq Y)P(X\leq Y)\quad (1)
$$
For the first part in the right-hand side of (1) we have that 
$$
P(Z\leq z|X>Y) = P(1\leq z|X>Y) = P(1\leq z) = \mathbb{1}_{[1,\infty)}(z).
$$
For the second part of (1) we have that 
\begin{align*}
P(Z\leq z|X\leq Y) &= P(X\leq zY|X\leq Y)\\
&=\begin{cases}
\frac{P(X\leq zY)}{P(X\leq Y)}, & z\leq 1\\
1, & z>1.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Then you just add all the pieces together.